# Implementation(s) of the algorithm on the GPU and on the CPU?

Tags: grammatical-number

The implementation of the algorithm on the GPU is introduced. The implementation of the algorithm on the CPU is also introduced.

If I want to combine the two sentences above into one, which of the following sentences is correct?

(a) The implementation of the algorithm on the GPU and on the CPU is introduced.
(b) The implementations of the algorithm on the GPU and on the CPU are introduced.
(c) The implementation of the algorithm on the GPU and the CPU is introduced.

Many Thanks!

Comment: "We introduce implementations of the algorithm on both the GPU and the CPU"?

Comment: Is this an algorithm that is newly implemented, but in ways specific for a CPU and a GPU?

Comment: @silves89: Yes, specific for a CPU and a GPU, respectively

Comment: "Implementations of the Bloom-Bloom-Plouffe Defrobnication Algorithm are introduced for both the GPU and the CPU"

Comment: Introduce to what? A new version of some software?

Comment: @DanBron : Thanks. I think your sentence is correct. Should I add "respectively" at the end of the sentence? i.e., We introduce implementations of the algorithm on both the GPU and the CPU respectively.

Comment: You could, but "respectively" is typically used to tie two *pairs* together, as in "we improved the performance of the algorithm 40% and 26% on the CPU and GPU respectively."

Comment: @silves89 : Thanks. This sentence appears in an academic paper. By "introduce", I mean that "the author introduces the procedure of the implementation to the readers."

Comment: @silves89 : "introduced [to the world] *in this paper*", as a debutante is introduced in her cotillion.

Comment: @silves89 : sorry, I think I am kind of wrong here. It is "an algorithm to do one thing". This algorithm includes several procedures. Some procedures are implemented on the GPU, and the others are implemented on the CPU.

Comment: 'The algorithm introduces procedures for execution on either the GPU or the CPU'?

Comment: @silve89 : The overall task requires the execution of one procedure on the CPU and the execution of the other procedure on the GPU. These two procedures are regarded as one algorithm because they are designed to finish one task.

Comment: Thanks. Is this getting closer? 'We introduce GPU and CPU specific procedures for the implementation of the algorithm.'

Comment: @silves89 : I decide to break up the original "algorithm" into "several algorithms". So is it correct to say: The implementations of the algorithms on the GPU and on the CPU are introduces ?

Comment: @silves89 sorry, it should be "The implementations of the algorithms on the GPU and on the CPU are introduced"

Comment: To me *implementation* means source code. Is the implementation that's new and special or is the algorithm?

Comment: Your phrasing could imply that you introduce two implementations: one that executes wholly on the CPU and one that executes wholly on the GPU. I'm not sure that's what you want?

Comment: @ silves89 : Thanks for your suggestions. I would consider refining my thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussions I'd say that maybe you want something like:

> We introduce distinct algorithms for GPU-appropriate procedures and for CPU-appropriate procedures.

Answer (score 2):

If there are two different algorithms, I would say

> "The implementations of the algorithms on the GPU and on the CPU are introduced."

If the algorithm is the same, but the implementations are different, I would say

> "The implementations of the algorithm on the GPU and the CPU are introduced."

If the algorithms are the same, and the implementations are the same, I would say

> "The implementation of the algorithm on the GPU and the CPU is introduced."